# Error propagation for arbitrary function with a very large number of variables

Tags: error, error-propagation

let's say I have some function, $f(\vec{x})$, whhere the input is a vector of very large size $\vec{x}=[x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n]$. n is tens of millions, but let's say for now it's just very large. I can of course calculate $f(\vec{x})$ for any given input, but it's a very complicated function so taking analytical derivatives isn't feasible. I also have the uncertainty on $\vec{x}$, $\vec{\sigma_\vec{x}}$. What I want to calculate but do not know how is the uncertainty on $f(\vec{x})$, $\sigma_{f(\vec{x})}$. Typical error propagation is not feasible because I cannot do such large numbers of function calls, also I can't calculate derivatives (except numerically). Kind of a "simple" approximation I came up with (which could very well be wrong) is simply evaluating $$\sigma_{f(\vec{x})}=|[f(\vec{x}+\vec{\sigma_{x}})-f(\vec{x}-\vec{\sigma_{x}})]/2|$$

I'm sure this isn't quite right but it's the closest I could come up with. Does anyone have any other ideas about this?

Comment: It is not clear what $\vec{\sigma_\vec{x}}$ [the uncertainty on $\vec{x}$] is measuring - usually you might expect a variance-covariance matrix

Comment: hello. Yes, let's say in this case the values of x and its uncertainty are empirical values. In essence, I measured them.

Comment: Are you saying that the scale of uncertainty on each $x_i$ is the same and errors in one are independent of errors in the others?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Are you saying that the scale of uncertainty on each  is the same". The uncertainty values are not the same for each , but they are known. I think it's safe to assume the uncertainties are independent though (so the covariance matrix is diagonal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of common methods to do this.

1. Linearize the function about the point estimate and then estimate uncertainty using the linear approximation. The **Extended Kalman Filter** (EKF) is an example where this is used. Based on your question this is not feasible since you can't get the derivative analytically.
2. Random sampling: Sample your input vector from the distribution, then apply your function to generate samples of the function value. Estimate the mean and covariance from the function output. This is commonly called the **Particle Filter**. Based on your question this one won't work for your application since it requires a large number of samples and function calls.
3. Deterministic Sampling: Approximate your uncertainty of the input with deterministic samples (much smaller number of samples required than in item 2). Propagate these samples through your function to estimate the mean and covariance of the function output. This is called the **Unscented Transform** (UT) and is the basis for the **Unscented Kalman Filter** (UKF). This seems like the most reasonable approach given what you've told us about the problem.

For more info on these three techniques please see this paper.
https://groups.seas.harvard.edu/courses/cs281/papers/unscented.pdf

The image below (from the paper) really gets the point across.

[image: Example of the UT for mean and covariance propagation. a) actual, b) first-order linearization (EKF), c) UT]

Comment: Wow! What an incredible technique! Thank you so much